# Eclipse ViewPart not showing a new panel

Tags: multithreading, eclipse-plugin

In my Eclipse plug-in I have a ViewPart that implements a ProgressListener.  I start my adding a frame that will display my data plot and then load data from a file, which calls my progressComplete() when done.  This works fine.

```
public void createPartControl(Composite parent) 
{
   parentComposite = parent;

   Composite composite = new Composite(parentComposite, SWT.EMBEDDED);
   m_frame = SWT_AWT.new_Frame(composite);

   String fileName = "/Users/fred/Documents/file.ipf";
   startFileLoad(fileName, -1);

    createActions();
}
```

However, I now want to remove the hardcoded file and have the user select a file from a button.  I am using an Action for this button (where, for now, the button calls the same hardcoded filename) as:

```
m_actionOpenDataFile = new Action() 
{
  public void run() 
  { 
      String fileName = "/Users/fred/Documents/file.ipf";
      startFileLoad(fileName, -1);
  } 
};
m_actionOpenDataFile.setText("Open");
m_actionOpenDataFile.setToolTipText("Open file");
m_actionOpenDataFile.setImageDescriptor(ImageDescriptor.createFromURL(ic.getURL("file.png")));
```

When selecting this button the action runs and the file is loaded, however the panel that displays the data is not shown on the Eclipse ViewPart.  Can anyone suggest why this is so?

```
public void progressComplete(ProgressInfo info)
{
  DataFile dataFile = (DataFile)info.getSource();
  if(dataFile != null)
  {
    try
    {
     TData data = new TData(dataFile, this, "data_progress");
     data.parsedFile();

     DataRender dataRender = new DataRender(this, data);
     DataPanel dataPanel = new DataPanel(data, dataRender);

     dataRender.setPanel(dataPanel.getBufferPanel());
     data.setAssociatedPanel(dataPanel);
     data.addParserProgressListener(dataPanel);

     m_frame.add(dataPanel);
```

When using the action button, I have attempted to pass the m_frame and ViewPart as part of the ProgressInfo, but the debug tells me that the variable cannot be accessed by the thread.

---

Thank you sgibly.  From your suggestion I wrote:

```
m_actionOpenDataFile = new Action() 
{
   public void run() 
   { 
     new UIJob("load data") 
     {
        public IStatus runInUIThread(IProgressMonitor monitor)
       {
          String fileName = "/Users/fred/Documents/file.ipf";
          startFileLoad(fileName, -1);
          return Status.OK_STATUS;
       }
     }.schedule(); 
  }
};
```

This still does not give any output on the display.  The Action run() creates a thread and this I guess creates the UI thread, or does it inherit the non UI properties?

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you get an invalid thread access exception. If this is the case, you are probably trying to access the UI from a non-UI thread.

To fix that, you can wrap the call for the `m_frame.add...` with a `UIJob`, schedule it and `join()` it, if you want the execution to be synchronized.

(another option is to use `Display -> syncExec()`, but I would stick to the `UIJob`)

Comment: Thanks, I added my attempt to use UIJob to the original post... the desired display is not yet visible. Am I applying your suggestion correctly?

Comment: Do you still get the error you got before? I see that you call `dataRender.setPanel...` and then `m_frame.add(dataPanel)`, so my question is what happens to the other components that were previously added to the Frame? Do you ever remove them. Also, you may need to re-layout your component (or cause for a refresh in some way).

Comment: I do not get the access error on the variable anymore. The dataPanel is the first thing that gets added to the m_frame, so for now there should not be a problem of removing them.  I tried adding a redraw() on the composite and a repaint() on the frame, but there is still not data plot -- I made sure that the data plot is still given when issuing the function calls outside of the Action button.

Comment: It's a little hard to tell what is the problem exactly without debugging it, but I have this idea you can try. `1.` Have your data loaded as before and render in the Frame so you can see it when you open the view. `2.` Try your action now to update the Frame with the new data and see what happens.